# I'm getting framework not found <library> when installing with cocoapods

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I installed Google Sign In via cocoapods, but when I tried to compile got this error

```
ld: framework not found GoogleAppUtilities
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

My Podfile is this:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '8.0'

target 'Project_name' do
  pod 'PayPal-iOS-SDK'
  pod 'Google/SignIn'
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Project_name

  target 'Project_nameTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'Project_nameUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

I installed the PayPal library first without problem.

I'm using .xcworkspace
Tried cleaning and building again, using $pod deintegrate
clean the project and $pod init again and nothing seems to change.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode, look in the Pods project for a file named GoogleAppUtilities.framework. It's probably under the Pods/Products folder. You need to add a reference to this file (GoogleAppUtilities.framework) in your main project. In you main app project file go to the build settings tab and look at the list named "Link Binary with Libraries"...you need to add a reference here to the GoogleAppUtilities.framework file.

Comment: Solved, I thank you.
Your answer did not solve the issue, but It gave me an idea.
I did that and in Build Settings->SearchPaths->FrameworkSearchPaths I added the framework in Debug and Release.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding your comment as the solution: it worked for mee too:

> Solved, I thank you. Your answer did not solve the issue, but It gave
> me an idea. I did that and in Build
> Settings->SearchPaths->FrameworkSearchPaths I added the framework in
> Debug and Release.